# SSIS Deployment: Dev Stage Live AppSettings

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

The main problem is: `How do i incorporate an appSettings.Config file with a particular build(dev, stage, live)?`  My appSettings.Config changes the conx strings for data sources based on which server the package is being deployed to.  I am able to go through Package configurations and add my appSettings.Config, however, I can only specifically add one file dev, stage, or live.  What i need to do is be able to build the solution and based on teh build type incorporate the dev/stage/live appsettings.  How could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could include all of the configuration files in the install and then just point to the correct one through an environment variable. I know you're wanting to switch the configuration file based on the solution build configuration, but you'll be looking at a complex solution when a simpler alternative exists.

Its quite straight-forward to add registry information during the package install that will set the machine's environment variable under the key:

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment\MyVariable
```

...to the path of the .dtsConfig for the current environment.