# SSIS Error: Failed to set the XML persistence events property for the Data Flow

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I have a package that imports 7 csv files and loads them into 7 corresponding tables. In dev, the package ran fine. In production when we went to run, 6 of the tables loaded but a small file targeted to load into the My_Table table failed with the following error.

I don't see much from Google on this and I have no clue why. Does anyone have a theory what the problem is?

```
Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility
Version 10.50.1600.1 for 64-bit
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2010. All rights reserved.

Started:  9:16:25 PM
Error: 2011-09-25 21:16:26.98
   Code: 0xC0040044
   Source: My_Table My_Table (SSIS.Pipeline)
   Description: Failed to set the XML persistence events property for the Data Flow objects.
End Error
Error: 2011-09-25 21:16:26.98
   Code: 0xC0040041
   Source: My_Table My_Table (SSIS.Pipeline)
   Description: Failed to load Data Flow objects
End Error
Error: 2011-09-25 21:16:26.98
   Code: 0xC0010018
   Source: My_Table 
   Description: Failed to load task "My_Table", type "SSIS.Pipeline.2". The contact information for this task is "Performs high-performance data extraction, transformation and loading;Microsoft Corporation; Microsoft SQL Server v10; (C) 2007 Microsoft Corporation; All Rights Reserved;http://www.microsoft.com/sql/support/default.asp;1".
End Error
```

Comment: Haven't seen it myself but just to ask some preliminary questions: Nobody has modified [DtExec.exe.config](http://bit.ly/uX0K7M)? Dev and prod are at the same SQL patch level? Dev matches prod w/64 bit proc? 1 package with 7 data flows? How was the package called in dev and prod (agent job, command line, right click and run)? Your production box is still RTM and that's pretty far out of date. [SP1 + CU3](http://bit.ly/oMFVzQ) is current patch level. Turn logging on in package, grab everything. Does it validate or error out before passing validation?

Comment: Can you address the above comments? I'd love some bounty but need more information about the problem.

Comment: No one modified the dtexec config that I am aware of. Dev and prod are on the same SQL Server level. I am not aware of differences in teh config file but have not been given a direct answer. The pkg was run in dev through a Tivoli scheduler running on the SQL dev box. We get another different error when we use the 32 bit dtexec: Data Flow objects cannot be loaded. Check if Microsoft.SqlServer.PipelineXml.dll is properly registered. we have no other issues running pkgs in prod with the 32 and 64 bit dtexec.

Comment: I think @billinkc's question about validation is an important one; I ran into a similar weird error in SSIS 2005 which turned out to be a missing registry key. I suggest validating (using `dtexec /va`) all possible combinations: DEV dtexec validating package on DEV server; DEV dtexec validating package on PROD server; PROD dtexec validating package on DEV server; and finally PROD dtexec validating package on PROD server. (This won't solve the problem by itself but will provide valuable debugging information.)

Comment: @billinkc please compare your config to `<configuration>
    <startup>
        <requiredRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
    </startup>
    <runtime>
        <gcServer enabled="true"/>
        <disableCommitThreadStack enabled="true"/>
        <generatePublisherEvidence enabled="false"/>
    </runtime>
</configuration>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by incorrect security settings for a couple of MS 2003 systems files used by SQL 2008 R2

SSIS packages that use Data Flow tasks.  Once I added the Service Account to these files, the TWS job worked.

That is why the SQL 2008 R2 SSIS packages that only execute stored procedures worked.

They do not have Data Flow tasks.

Comment: Listing those files would be EXTREMELY helpful :)

Comment: I'm sorry, Its been too long. I don't remember. I should have mentioned it at the time. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like there's an issue with one or more configuration files on the production server. I would start by looking at the SSIS configuration file on production. You should be able to find the file here:

```
%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\90\DTS\Binn
```

Compare it to the SSIS configuration file on DEV, and merge any differences into production. I would verify that all package-level configuration files have been deployed properly too.

This SO question may offer some insight to deplying package configurations to difference environments:
 [SSIS Deployment: Dev Stage Live AppSettings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856263/ssis-deployment-dev-stage-live-appsettings)

If any of your packages are stored outside of the root folder, you can follow this article:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/harshjshah/archive/2007/05/19/hands-on-change-the-ssis-configuration-file-and-add-a-root-level-folder-to-the-stored-packages.aspx